# Illustrator: how to set up document for 6x3" banner?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, logo, print-production

I'm making a banner for a client 6" tall X 3" wide.

I gave the client a 72x36" PDF file, but they came back asking for a larger size? What did I do wrong and how do I fix it?

**Client feedback**

Unfortunately, it appears to be the same file (.5" x 1"). Would be helpful to have the art at size to be output.

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> makes a new file
- Choose Inches in the Units dropdown
- Type **3** and **6** in Width and Height boxes
- Move your artwork into this new document, rescale so it fits this new page, save again, send again